# Are normally distributed sample means equivalent to normally distributed residuals?

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, t-test, residuals, normality-assumption

According to [t-test:Assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Assumptions) "The means of the two populations being compared should follow normal distribution"

The one way ANOVA test in case of 2 groups equals the t-test but the ANOVA assumption on normality according to [ANOVA:Assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Randomization-based_analysis) is defined by "the distributions of the residuals are normal."

**Question:** Can I conclude that ***"means of sample distributions are normally distributed"*** is equivalent to ***"the distributions of the residuals are normal"***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia link you give are using imprecise/confounded language, so you should maybe find some better tutorial!  It also confuses assumptions and mathematical conclusions from those assumptions (it isn't an assumption that $S^2$ *follows a $\chi^2$-distribution with $n − 1$ degrees of freedom*, that can be concluded from the normal assumption and independence.) **Find a better guide**!

As to the question, does normal distribution of the sample means imply normal distribution of the residuals? **If** the sampling distribution of the sample means are **exactly** normal, then the residuals will be normal. But, if you only have some approximate normal sampling distribution of the sample means, then that conclusion **do not follow**.

---

Your extra question in comment: Can I argue as follows: the central limit theorem states that if the sample size is large enough, the distribution of the means is close enough to the normal distribution and can I therefore assume that the residuals are normally distributed?

**No**, that is wrong. If you have a sample $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ from some non-normal distribution, but the CLT applies and $\bar{X}_n$ is approximately normal, the residuals are $X_i−\bar{X}_n$, and its distribution is mostly that of $X_i$, non-normal (but recentered). The reason that the residual distribution form is mostly that of $X_i$, is that the mean has much lower variance.

Comment: Can I argue as follows: the central limit theorem states that if the sample size is large enough, the distribution of the means is close enough to the normal distribution and can I therefore assume that the rediduals are normally distributed?

Comment: **No**, that is wrong. If you have a samle $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ from some non-normal distribution, but the clt applies and $\bar{X}_n$ is approximately normal, the residuals are $X_i-\bar{X}_n$, and its distribution is mosly that of $X_i$, non-normal (but recetered). The reason that the residual distribution form is mostly that of $X_i$, is that the mean has much lower variance.